# WinTabber not running with wine on 12.10

Tags: wine, window-manager

I tried to run this with the program from `properties` and below is what I get from the terminal.

I looked around for a fix for it but I don't really know what to look for.

I also tried installing .NET Framework 2.0 as well, but I ran into quite a bit of errors and I am not sure if it installed properly or not. I really would like to get this software running on here since I can't find any other tabbed window managers similar to this one. Do any of you know wha

```
adkins526@ubuntu:~$ env WINEPREFIX="/home/zadkins526/.wine" wine C:\\Program\ Files\\WinTabber\ \(Freeware\)\\wintabber.exe 
err:module:import_dll Library mscoree.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727\\mscorsvw.exe") not found
err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Main exe initialization for L"C:\\windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727\\mscorsvw.exe" failed, status c0000135
err:service:service_send_start_message service L"clr_optimization_v2.0.50727_32" failed to start
fixme:service:scmdatabase_autostart_services Auto-start service L"clr_optimization_v2.0.50727_32" failed to start: 1053
err:module:import_dll Library MSVBVM60.DLL (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\WinTabber (Freeware)\\wintabber.exe") not found
err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Main exe initialization for L"C:\\Program Files\\WinTabber (Freeware)\\wintabber.exe" failed, status c0000135
```

Answer (score 0):

My bet is.. WinTabber is not going to work for native Linux programs. It hooks itself to Windows's window manager. I'm not too familiar with wine's internals, maybe it could work for other programs running under wine. Anyway, thanks for the tip. I'll try WinTabber on my Windows machine. :)